# Add laravel migrations with foreign keys

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, migration

I have created a table called 'users'.There are tables called 'companies','designations','departments'.I want to add company_id,designation_id,department_id columns to users table as foreign keys.

I tried this but it didn't work

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->integer('department_id');
        $table->integer('company_id');
        $table->integer('designation_id');

        $table->foreign('department_id')->references('id')->on('departments')->onDelete('restrict')->onUpdate('restrict');
        $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onDelete('restrict')->onUpdate('restrict');
        $table->foreign('designation_id')->references('id')->on('designations')->onDelete('restrict')->onUpdate('restrict');



    });
}


public function down()
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn(['department_id','company_id','designation_id']);
    });
}
```

When I migrate the migration it shows this error.

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General
>   error: 1005 Can't create table `lanwadb`.`users` (errno: 150 "Foreign
>   key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `users` add
>   constraint `users_department_id_foreign` foreign key (`department_id`)
>   references `departments` (`id`) on delete restrict on update restrict)

Designation migration as follows,

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('designations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestampsTz();
        });
    }
```

Department migration as follows,

````
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('departments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('company_id');
            $table->timestampsTz();
        });
    }
    ```
````

Comment: First of all you should use `unsignedInteger` for your foreign key... Expecially if you  setted the `departments`, `company` and `designation` table ids as `increment` field.. Please post also the other migrations so we can help you in a more precise way... But usually when `Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed` is thrown it's because the 2 columns doesn't have the same format

Comment: @IlGala Yes I have used increment fields for departments, companies, and designations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make relationship the foreign key field should be `index`ed. Here you have three columns you want to use as foreign key `'company_id'`, `'department_id'` and `'designation_id'`. In Laravel migration you can use `unsigned()` function to `index` them.

Example:

```
$table->integer('department_id')->unsigned();
$table->integer('company_id')->unsigned();
$table->integer('designation_id')->unsigned();
```

There is another function called `unsignedInteger()` by which you can make a column both Integer and Unsigned.

```
$table->unsignedInteger('department_id');
$table->unsignedInteger('company_id');
$table->unsignedInteger('designation_id');
```

Comment: I learned a new thing from you. Thank you very much for your support.

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
    $table->integer('department_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->integer('company_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->integer('designation_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->foreign('department_id')->references('id')->on('departments')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('departments')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    $table->foreign('designation_id')->references('id')->on('departments')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
```